# Writing a specific if else statement on Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing an assembler with Python, and I just need some help writing an if else statement. I have the following machine language instruction that I want to convert to binary.

```
@i

D=M // D=i

@100

D=D-A // D=i-100
```

How would I write a statement, so that it deletes/ignores the comments and spaces.  The way I see it, it's going to delete/ignore anything that follows a / , and skip the line until it reaches a letter but I'm not sure how to write this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line=line.strip()
    if line:
     if '//' in line:
         ind=line.find('//')
         print(line[:ind])
     else:
         print(line)
```

**output**:

```
@i
D=M 
@100
D=D-A
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example below.

if-else codeblock:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

var1 = 100
if var1:
   print "1 - Got a true expression value"
   print var1
else:
   print "1 - Got a false expression value"
   print var1

var2 = 0
if var2:
   print "2 - Got a true expression value"
   print var2
else:
   print "2 - Got a false expression value"
   print var2

print "Good bye!"
```

output:

```
1 - Got a true expression value
100
2 - Got a false expression value
0
Good bye!
```

if-elif-else codeblock:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

var = 100
if var == 200:
   print "1 - Got a true expression value"
   print var
elif var == 150:
   print "2 - Got a true expression value"
   print var2
elif var == 100:
   print "3 - Got a true expression value"
   print var
else:
   print "4 - Got a false expression value"
   print var

print "Good bye!"
```

output:

```
3 - Got a true expression value
100
Good bye!
```